# How to put the footnote after the tcolorbox not the bottom?

Tags: footnotes, tcolorbox

Is it possible to put the footnote text just **after** the tcolorbox environment not at the bottom as shown below? I also want to remove the footnoterule.

[image]

the style above is implemented as

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[breakable]{tcolorbox}

\begin{document}

  \begin{tcolorbox}
    {\bfseries random letters:}

    sadghughr ijebgengek fdingelmgpea$^a$

  \end{tcolorbox}

  $^a$ inside tcolorbox
\end{document}
```

Comment: You can probably achieve this using `\footnotemark` and `\footnotetext` and wrapping the `tcolorbox` inside a `minipage`. This would be a straightforward approach.

Comment: @JasperHabicht thanks, that would be a concise solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An `endnotes` attempt (currently doesn't work for nested `tcolorbox` envs):

```tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{endnotes}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}

\makeatletter
\AtBeginEnvironment{tcolorbox}{%
  \setcounter{endnote}{0}%
  \renewcommand\theendnote{\alph{endnote}}%
  % uncomment next line if you prefer \footnote than \endnote
  % \let\footnote\endnote
}

\AfterEndEnvironment{tcolorbox}{%
  \ifnum\c@endnote>0
    \begingroup
    \let\enoteheading=\@empty
    \theendnotes
    \endgroup
  \fi
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{tcolorbox}
  content\endnote{note} content\endnote{another note}
\end{tcolorbox}

\begin{tcolorbox}
  content
\end{tcolorbox}

\begin{tcolorbox}
  content\endnote{note2} content\endnote{another note2}
\end{tcolorbox}

\begin{tcolorbox}
  content\endnote{note3} content\endnote{another note3}
  \begin{tcolorbox}
    content\endnote{note31} content\endnote{another note31}
  \end{tcolorbox}
\end{tcolorbox}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Excellent, I didn't know the package `endnote` before, you just open a window for me. By the way, could you tell me in which package the command `\AtBeginEnvironment{ }{ }` and `\AtBeginEnvironment{ }{ }` is defined? or they are contained in `\TeX` ?

Comment: The nested tcolorbox env is not inevitable for me, so it doesn't matter.

Comment: For a long time `\AtBeginEnvironment` and similar hook commands are provided by `etoolbox` package, and since latex2e 2020-10-01, they're supported directly by the latex2e kernel. `tcolorbox` options `before (app|pre)`, `after (app|pre)` play a similar role.

Answer (score 2):

This would be a straightforward, pure LaTeX approach. It can probably be solved more elegantly, but just in case everything else breaks:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}

\newenvironment{fnwrapper}{%
    \noindent%
    \begin{minipage}{\textwidth}%
    \renewcommand{\thefootnote}{\alph{footnote}}%
    \renewcommand{\footnoterule}{}%
}{%
    \end{minipage}%
}

\begin{document}

Hello!\footnote{foo}

\bigskip

\begin{fnwrapper}
\begin{tcolorbox}
Boxed hello\footnotemark[1]

Another boxed hello\footnotemark[2]
\end{tcolorbox}
\footnotetext[1]{bar}
\footnotetext[2]{baz}
\end{fnwrapper}

\bigskip

Hello again\footnote{qux}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: thanks for your solution, that's what I want.